# How to compare a item.date in a collection to a date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

The query below:

```
IEnumerable<activity> activityList = PortalContext.activity.Where(item => 
item.schakeling_id == newActivity.schakeling_id && 
item.startdt.Date == DateTime.Now.Date);
```

I am getting this error:

> "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported."

I have tried multiple different ways but can't get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475290/linq-to-entities-datetime-compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a date variable outside of your query:

```
var currentdate=DateTime.Now.Date;

var activityList = PortalContext.activity.Where(item => 
                   item.schakeling_id == newActivity.schakeling_id 
                   && item.startdt.Date == currentdate);
```

Comment: Really strange. I though and am alomst sure that is the solution also. Somehow it is not working with me. Going home now, take a look at it tomorrow

Comment: I executed that query in linqpad and it worked, but try later  with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(item.startdt)==currentDate`

Comment: This worked for me! Really strange. I am sure I used your first answer in earlier projects. Any idea why?

Comment: I really don't have idea, maybe is EF version. What I did to test it was to use Linqpad and it worked, if I find out the answer I will let you know;)

Comment: I marked your response as the answer to my question. I also edited it with you're remarks for other people.